# Handle zulu datetime from json object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I get from APIs different time attributes:

```
"created_at": "2017-08-18T18:54:02.30709Z",
"updated_at": "2021-05-25T10:20:49.833322Z",
"publishedAt": "2021-05-25T05:25:27Z",
```

I would like to save them in the database:

```
$table->timestamp('created_at');
$table->timestamp('updated_at');
$table->timestamp('published_at');
```

Unfortunately, they are saved with the wrong time. So `2021-05-25T05:25:27Z` is stored as `2021-05-25 05:25:27 GMT+2` in the database without offset.

What is the best way to use Laravel to transfer this data from an API to the database?

Answer (score 0):

funtion with

```
return \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::parse($string)->setTimezone(config('app.timezone'));
```

works.